# How to build California map

Tags: r, ggplot2

```
ca_base + theme_nothing() + 
+     geom_polygon(data = ca_county, fill = NA, color = "white") +
+     geom_polygon(color = "black", fill = NA)
```

I used the above code to create a map of California but I have trouble changing this map type into a real Google image.

Comment: it would be easier to help If provide your sample data

Comment: i just have to map the state california in satellite image.

Comment: use ggmap package

Answer (score 0):

Guessing you're learning R.

Use qmap:

```
qmap('california', zoom=6, maptype='road')
```

in satellite:

```
qmap('california', zoom=6, maptype='satellite')
```